# Inheritance and association relationships in UML

Tags: object-oriented-design, uml, inheritance, class-diagram

I was creating a class model using inheritance, and have a situation I don't know how to represent.

For this question I built an example diagram in which I have a class `Person` with some attributes.

I also have a class `Class1` that needs to use objects of a new class with `Person`'s attributes plus `sex` and `birthDate` attributes, so I create a `Person2` class which inherits from `Person`.

But I also have another class `Class2` which needs to use objects with only the `Person` attributes, not `Person2`. I can't use an association relationship because `Person` is an abstract class.

How should I handle this situation?

[image: Example UML diagram labelling the relationship in question]

Comment: " I can't do an association relationship because Person it's a abstract class" - of course you can, it doesn't matter that Person is abstract. The association relationship means that you are associated with the abstract *type* (your Class2 "sees" only the methods and properties in the Person type, because your `person: Person` attribute has that type), but you can assign a Person2 instance to the variable (that's what inheritance allows you to do - substitute a derived type where an object of the base class is expected). P.S. your inheritance arrow should go from Person2 to Person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your diagram does not correspond to the narrative:

- In your diagram, `Person` inherits from `Person2`. So `Person2` would be an anonymous person without any name. Not very useful.

  To let`Person2` inherit from `Person` (in UML-speak we say that `Person2` is a specialization of `Person`), you must have the triangle arrow head on the side of `Person`. Note that `Person2` has a `name`, but it's not directly accessible: it can only be accessed via public methods of `Person`, since it's private.
- Your diagram does not give any clue about `Person` being abstract. The usual way is to write the name of abstract classes in italic.

After correction, it would look like:
[image]

`Class2` **may perfectly be associated with an abstract class**. The only thing that `Class2` may not do in this case, is to instantiate (i.e. create an object of) the `Person`. But it may very well get the `Person` object from somewhere else. For example: since `Person2` is a `Person`, a `Class1` object may invoke a method of a `Class2` object passing `person` as a `Person` parameter.  Or `Class2` could use an injected [factory](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) that would create instances of concrete specializations of `Person`.

There are **plenty of practical uses** of associations with abstract classes. For example, it's used for making [observers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#Structure), or the more complex [interpreter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern).